# i need a popupview when clicking button and again clicking i want to disapper that view in objective c

Tags: objective-c

Here is the code that I am using for popup:

```
-(void)popup:(id)sender
{
  //button action
  UIView *popView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(Screen_Width-200,40, self.view.frame.size.width-130, self.view.frame.size.height/2-60)];
    [popView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    popView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self.view addSubview: popView];
}
```

Comment: Have you written the code to call this method?

Comment: You should make your own UIViewObject, that has a button, and all the logic you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this in your `viewDidLoad`. So it's hidden bydefault.

```
UIView *popView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(Screen_Width-200,40, self.view.frame.size.width-130, self.view.frame.size.height/2-60)];
[popView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
popView.hidden = YES;
popView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[self.view addSubview: popView];
```

On your button click show it like,
     `popView.hidden = NO;`

And take `UITapGestureRecognizer` on main View or root view and on touches call,

```
popView.hidden = YES;
```

Exaample of `TapGestureRecognizer`

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                      action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
[self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
//The event handling method
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

   popView.hidden = YES;
  }
```

Hope this will help :)